# Android activities navigation flow problem

Tags: android

I have activity A that starts activity B(singleInstance). In activity B there is a back button, which starts intent to activity A.

A -> B -> A

I want to achieve following behaviour:

User triggers B on A, after that press my back button, returns to activity A and press devices's hardware back button, which navigates him to device's home screen.

Now it looks like that: 
User triggers B on A, after that press my back button, returns to activity A and press devices's hardware back button, which navigates him again to activity A, then press back button again and open activity B. Then he presses back button and activity A occurs and it is an endless loop....

I can not use flag NO_HISTORY, because I want to save state of activity B from some other reasons. Activity B is a webBrowser so I have overloaded methods onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save in cache website which was loaded.

Right now I overloaded onBackPressed method in activity A , by starting an intent to home screen, but it is not a good solution.

Do you have any other ideas?

Here is the code:

Activity A:
`Intent browser = new Intent(this, B.class);
this.startActivity(browser);`

Activity B:
`   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                           super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            callWebViewMethod("saveState", new Class[] { Bundle.class }, 
                    new Object[] { savedInstanceState });
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

```
    callWebViewMethod("restoreState", new Class[] { Bundle.class }, 
            new Object[] { savedInstanceState });
}   
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView != null) {
        if ( ( Boolean )callWebViewMethod( "canGoBack" ) )
        {
            callWebViewMethod("goBack");
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity( getBackIntent() );
        }
    }
}
private Intent getBackIntent() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    // some code here           
    i.setClass(this, A.class);
    return i;
}`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
after that press my back button
```

`finish() activity B` here..

remove `onBackPressed`method from your activity A.

Comment: When I put finish() in Activity B I will lost loaded web page and I do not want it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to navigate back to Activity, you can try to put `finish();` after your `startActivity();`

Comment: When I put finish() in Activity B I will lost loaded web page and I do not want it. I also tried to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag on intent from activity B to A, but it also does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView != null) {
        if ( ( Boolean )callWebViewMethod( "canGoBack" ) )
        {
            callWebViewMethod("goBack");
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity( getBackIntent() );
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to create a new Intent to go back to Activity A. Just get rid of the Else condition.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView != null) {
            if ( ( Boolean )callWebViewMethod( "canGoBack" ) )
            {
                callWebViewMethod("goBack");
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed(); // pass to the default handler
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it work as expected in activity B, but when I returns to activity A it makes another instance of it, and then when i press back button it goes back to activity B. See below:

A1 -> B -> A2 -> A1 -> B -> A -> B -> ...

Comment: Can you post the code you have in your Activity A and Activity B classes please.

Comment: If I will do that, I will deprive user from possibility of going back to activity A by triggering back button...

Comment: Sorry, please see my amendment. If you call super.onBackPressed the default handler will do it's job.

Comment: Thank you @C0deAttack for all your coments. Your solution works, but the problem is that i have some additional logic in my method `getBackIntent` and I am afraid than I cannot resign from it. Is there any way to do that with an intent from activity B to A ? In addition I will lost savedInstanceState when I will trigger super.onBackPressed, because it will finish my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override onBackPressed, don't call finish.
When you start each activity, set the intent flags to

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
```

Comment: If I reorder activity A to front, I will still have activity B behind. I want to go from activity A to device's home screen by pressing back button.

Now I have A1 -> B -> A2 -> A1 -> B -> A -> B -> ....
I will have A -> B -> A -> B -> A -> B 

Please notice than in activity B I have overwritten onBackPressed method which creates new intent and this is the reason why it is looping. Question is, how to save web browser state and clear activity B from backButton navigation history??

Comment: As I suggested - don't override onbackPressed. You will have one instance only of A and of B. If you go to B a second time from A, it will be in the same state as when you left it by means of the back button

Answer (score 0):

While jumping from A>B A to B create the new intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

When you press back from the activity B just call the onBackPressed method

```
onBackPressed();
```

when you fall back to activity A and u want to jump to HomeActivity from A override the onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,HomeActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
```

If you are jumping from B to home and them press back it will jump back to the last opened activity because android maintain the stack of your activity. Make sure finish() the activity if you don't want the activity in your activity stack or you can clear the whole stack by using this code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This will create the new Activity and their wont be any stack.